# Simple matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation

If I have a square matrix $A_{n \times n}$, then the $ij$ entry in $A^2$ can be defined as follows $$\large{c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}}$$

Now I want a summation formula like the above but for a general $A^k$ what will it be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for the entry at place $(i,j)$ of $A^3$ is
$$
\sum_{k_1=1}^n
\sum_{k_2=1}^n
a_{ik_1}a_{k_1k_2}a_{k_2j}
$$
The other powers are done in a similar way.

Indeed, if $a^{(r)}_{ij}$ denotes the coefficient at place $(i,j)$ in $A^r$, we have
$$
a^{(3)}_{ij}=\sum_{k_1=1^n}a_{ik_1}a^{(2)}_{k_1j}=
\sum_{k_1=1}^n a_{ik_1}\biggl(\sum_{k_2=1}^n a_{k_1k_2}a_{k_2j}\biggr)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the Einstein's sum convention to get
$$a^2{}_{ij}=a_{ik}a_{kj}$$
$$a^3{}_{ij}=a_{ik}a_{kl}a_{lj}$$
$$...$$
$$a^n{}_{ij}=a_{ik}a_{kl}\cdots a_{ms}a_{sj}$$